# Display a leading zero AND a tailing zero in an R object imported through a SQL query

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I need to produce a print statement of any type (I would prefer cat or paste for consistency with the rest of the work).

The problem I have is I can not find a way to print an object of the form XX.XX when it has a leading zero and a tailing zero, for example 07.20.

Normally this would not be a problem but the object comes from a database via a RODBC SQL query.

I can achieve a leading zero usually in the following way:

```
X <- paste(SQL QUERY HERE)

report <- formatC(as.vector(t(RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, X))),
                  width = 5, flag = "0")
```

however for a character with a leading and tailing zero this will print the following:

```
paste(report)

007.2
```

The following will produce a tailing zero:

```
report <- formatC(as.vector(t(RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, X))),
                  format = 'f', digits = 2)
paste(report)

7.20
```

Any combination of the two methods seems to just favour one and produces one of the above results.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `dput(as.vector(t(RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, X))))` for one or two cases of interest for you? I suppose this has not much to do with RODBC

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. The output from `formatC(dput(as.vector(t(RODBC::sqlQuery(ch, X)))),
        format = 'f', digits = 2)` is 7.20.

Comment: I need the output *before* the formatting: could you please remove `formatC` and repost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few examples just to fix ideas (still can't understand what you need):

```
## val <- as.vector(t(RODBC::sqlQuery(channel, X)))
val <- 7.2
sprintf("%05.2f", val)
val <- "007.2"
sprintf("%05.2f", as.numeric(val))
```